# Counting number of occurrences in PyTorch Tensor. (Tensor is too big for Numpy)

Tags: python, pytorch, unique, tensor

Is there any smart way to count the number of occurrences of each value in a very Large PyTorch Tensor? Tensor Size is `11701*300=3510300` or maybe increase or decrease.
`TORCH.BINCOUNT, TORCH.UNIQUE and TORCH.UNIQUE_CONSECUTIVE` are not useful so far.

BINCOUNT returns a different number of elements every time. Unique is also not useful as it returns unique values.

[image]

This is what I meant when I said it returns different elements every time. If 5 elements will return 8 elements tensor, How I am supposed to know which elements are how many times. this is confusing for me. The official documentation has limited content and there is no other website, explains it.

In the above picture. So, 5 is 2 times. 0 is? what 0 times? How to read this output. it doesn't make any sense to me.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "BINCOUNT returns a different number of elements every time"? If you apply on the same tensor it should return the same result every time. If every time you have a new tensor for which the `max(input)` is different, then you get  different number of elements.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the problem is how you read the output. The output of `torch.bincount` is a tensor of size `max(input)+1`, that means it covers all bins of size 1 from zero to `max(input)`. Therefore, in the output tensor from the first element you see how many 0, 1, 2, ..., `max(input)` are there in your non-negative integral array.

For example:

```
t1 = torch.randint(0,10, (20,))
print(t1)

tensor([2, 5, 7, 3, 1, 2, 7, 8, 8, 0, 5, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 0, 6, 6])
```

in this tensor the max value is 8 (9 did not appear by chance), so it gives:

```
print(torch.bincount(t1).size())
print(torch.bincount(t1))

torch.Size([9])
tensor([2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2])
```

that means, in the tensor `t1` there are two 0s, one 1, two 3s, ..., and two 8s.